# Iterate over double values to produce page numbers

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, for-loop

I have 35 items separated in 3 pages. Page 1 and page 2 have 15 items and page 3 have a 5. Now I'm already create loop to tell the script where to go. Here is the script.

```
for i in range(1,36):
    if i <= 15:
        page = 1
        item = i
    if i > 15 <= 30:
        page = 2
        item = i - 15
    if i > 30 <= 35:
        page = 3
        item = i - 30

    print 'GOTO page %s take item %s' % (page, item)
```

But in the future there can be 1000 pages with 25 items on the page. So I'm changing the script as follows. But now I need to add more `if` statements like `if i > items_per_page * 22 <= items_per_page * 23:` What is a better and more Pythonic way to get the same?

```
max_items = 35
items_per_page = 15

for i in range(1, max_items + 1):
    if i <= items_per_page:
        page = 1
        item = i
    if i > items_per_page <= items_per_page * 2:
        page = 2
        item = i - items_per_page
    if i > items_per_page * 2 <= items_per_page * 3:
        page = 3
        item = i - items_per_page * 2

    print 'GOTO page %s take item %s' % (page, item)
```

Comment: Note: your conditions are odd. You could use `elif`s and avoid repeating the same comparisons: `if i <= x: ... elif i <= 2*x: ... elif i <= 3*x`.  Also, sure chain comparisons works but they are best used when they look familiar. And I'd say that the form `a > b < c` isn't familiar. I'd probably prefer to use an explicit chaining in that case (besides, as I said, you could simply avoid the double comparison using `elif`s *in this specific instance*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use maths:

```
def page_number(item, items_per_page):
    # 1-based numbering assumed; first item is 1, first page is 1
    return (item - 1) // items_per_page + 1
```

For 15 items per page, this correctly states that item 31 is on page 3:

```
>>> page_number(30, 15)
2
>>> page_number(31, 15)
3
```

and scales all the way to page 1000 for the 25-items-per-page case:

```
>>> page_number(25005, 25)
1001
```

Just use that in your loop:

```
for i in range(1, max_items + 1):
    page = page_number(i, items_per_page)
    item = i - (page - 1) * items_per_page
    print 'GOTO page %s take item %s' % (page, item)
```

No `if` statements needed.

Generally speaking, if the number of `if` statements depends on the number of items for the loop, you are going about it the wrong way.

Comment: you are the king! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
page = ( (i-1) // items_per_page ) + 1
item = ( (i-1) % items_per_page ) + 1
```

Comment: Use `//` for Python 3, otherwise you'll get float objects. You can use the `divmod()` function to calculate *both* the remainder and the quotient.

Comment: The question does have a python2.7 tag but thanks for the tips.. didn't know python had divmod

Comment: Yup, but `//` works in Python 2 too and you could still use `from __future__ import true_division` to get the same division behaviour in 2.